# Using bash's expanded variable in awk

Tags: bash, awk

Here is scaled down version of issue I am working on.

I am using bash to get following info and storing it into a bash variable named "c".

```
echo {1..3}
1 2 3
echo \${1,2,3}
$1 $2 $3
c=$(echo \${1,2,3})
echo $c
$1 $2 $3
```

Now I want to use variable "c" inside awk statement, wanted to know is it even possible or I am thinking far from reality.

```
echo a b c d e f g h |awk -v c=$"(echo \${1,2,3})" '{print c}'
(echo ${1,2,3}) #This is not expected, instead a b c was.
```

or

```
  echo a b c d e f g h |awk -v c="$(echo \${1,2,3})" '{print c}'
  $1 $2 $3
```

I know I can do this using for loop inside awk. But in my requirement, column numbers I am interested in are totally random , so could not use loop over them. Which makes following way not usable.

Like this

```
echo a b c d e f g h |awk '{print $1,$2,$3}'
a b c
```

or like this:

```
 echo a b c d e f g h |awk '{for(i=1;i<=3;i++) printf "%s ", $i}'
a b c
```

## query:

Wanted to know if its possible to store all column numbers it a list/array/variable and throw them to print in awk ?

## Note:

This is a real scaled down version of original data.

Comment: `c=$"(echo \${1,2,3})"` SHOULD give you `(echo ${1,2,3})`. [This is definitely expected.](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#i18nl10n)

Comment: Why? You could just pass `1` and `3` to awk and let awk expand that to a list of values in the range.

Comment: It's random , sometime it's 1-3 and then 6,7,8,10,12,13,14..... . So I need to list these column number in a list out of awk body ,for others to maintain the code .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest passing the array of column numbers like this:

```
cols=( {1..3} )
awk -v a="${cols[*]}" 'BEGIN { n = split(a, cols) } 
    { for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) printf "%s%s", $(cols[i]), (i<n?OFS:ORS) }'
```

Note that I'm using `${cols[*]}` so that the shell doesn't split the elements of the array into separate words.

Comment: Eeks! I missed out that you had used `${cols[@]}` instead of `${cols[*]}` and had upvoted anyway. Thanks for correction.

Comment: thanks Tom for solving problem, Just curious if its even possible with variables ?

Comment: It sounds like maybe you want to pass `$1, $2, $3` as a string and then have awk `eval` that string...hopefully there's an alternative way to solve your problem!